# What is actually the minimal autotools files layout to be shipped with my source

Tags: cross-platform, autotools

Having made my `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am` files, I see myself having to perform `autoreconf`s so autoconf will not complain about undefined macros such as `AC_INIT_AUTOMAKE`. This fills my directory with files like `aclocal.m4`, `Makefile.in`, `install-sh`,  `confdefs.h`, `depcomp`, `autom4te.cache`, and a `.deps` directory.

Having read the documentation I just cannot get what are the minimum number of these files to be shipped with my source code, that are platform independant. Either the documentation is not clear enough, they expect me to read much more or it is me that I don’t have enough time. I am sort of in a rush.

What are these files and what are the tasks that the compiler person, in their system, must perform?

Comment: For someone wanting to just compile and install your project the `dist` target family create tarballs, these files should be enough. For someone wanting to participate to your project I guess you have to distribute all the non generated files because this kind of user should have installed all the development tools needed to generate them

Comment: @Kwariz post that as an answer and I will pick it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For someone wanting to just compile and install your project the dist target family create tarballs, these files should be enough. For someone wanting to participate to your project I guess you have to distribute all the non generated files because this kind of user should have installed all the development tools needed to generate them

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I switched to CMake anyway. :P